# RecyclerView scrolling with pull down refresh

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using a RecrylerView to display name of Songs, song length and Artist which is stored in SQL server. How do I implement pull down refresh?

Comment: what is your concrete issue with pull down to refresh implementation?

Comment: @R.Kirill The issue is that I don't know what is the standard way of implementing it, I am new to Android development.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html might help you.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I implement pull down refresh?

You can use `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` enclose your layout inside   **SwipeRefreshLayout**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout  
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/itemsRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

> Java

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {  
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // Refresh items
        refreshItems();
    }
});
```

#### See this for [more info](http://sapandiwakar.in/pull-to-refresh-for-android-recyclerview-or-any-other-vertically-scrolling-view/)